# Using the Explorer context menu to copy a modified version of the file path to the clipboard

Tags: windows, powershell, explorer, wsh, windows-scripting

The requirement I've got is pretty straightforward, but I'm struggling sifting through the huge amounts of unrelated information on the subject.

**Requirement**

I have files synchronised between my PC and my web server. Basically I need to be able to right click on a local file and copy the equivalent server path (with some additional string manipulation logic) to the clipboard.

**Approach**

I guess what I need done is the following:

1. Add a Windows Explorer context menu option to execute a WSH script passing the full file path and name as a parameter.
2. Create a Windows Scripting Host script that will accept that paramater, do necessary string manipulation, and copy to clip board.

The string manipulation I can handle fine (preferably in VBScript). It's the whole passing a parameter to the WSH script that I can't really find any info about.

Alternately, I wouldn't mind if this was done with PowerShell (if applicable) so that I can learn a bit more about it while I'm at it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've answered the question below.

Answer (score 1):

You can access a parameter in VB script thus:

```
WScript.Echo(WScript.Arguments(0))
```

When you register a shell context menu command, you can pass the path and filename as a parameter by registering:

```
wscript.exe "C:\...full path...\myscript.vbs" "%1"
```

Comment: That didn't quite work. I used the following and it's fine now:

`wscript.exe "[fullpath]\myscript.vbs" "%1"`

Added this to they default value in this registry key:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy Server Path\Command`

Now just writing the vbs script (I'll post that up later for anyone else that might want it).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've modified a VBS script by that registers itself in the Explorer context menu and the allows you to right click on a file to copy it's corresponding server URL to the clipboard.

```
'####################################################################
' If you sync files between your local PC and a web server you can use this
' script to right-click on one of those files to copy the corresponding server
' URL to your clipboard
'####################################################################
Option Explicit

'Local path to the directory that is being synchronised with the server
Const constRootWinPath = "C:\SyncedFiles"
'path to corresponding directory on the server
Const constRootServerPath = "/SyncedFiles/"
'Domain name of the server
Const constServerDomain = "http://mydomain.dom/"
'MAKE SURE TO INCLUDE LEADING AND TRAILING SLASHES ON ALL PATHS!!!!!

Dim objIE

' Parse the command line arguments
If WScript.Arguments.Count      <> 1 Then Syntax
If WScript.Arguments.Named.Count = 1 Then
    If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists( "Register" ) Then
        Register
    ElseIf WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists( "Unregister" ) Then
        UnRegister
    Else
        Syntax
    End If
End If

' Check arguments. Text argument gets processed as a path. 
If WScript.Arguments.UnNamed.Count = 1 Then

    Dim strArgument
    strArgument = WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)

    'The file has to exist within a directory under constRootWinPath so that we know how to process the path
    If instr(trim(strArgument),trim(constRootWinPath)) > 0 Then
        'WScript.Echo """" & constRootWinPath & """ was found in """ & strArgument & """"
        SendToClipboard(ProcessLocalPathToServerPath(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)))
    Else
        WScript.Echo """" & constRootWinPath & """ not found in """ & strArgument & """. Please make sure to edit the Const in the VBS file"
    End If
End If


Function ProcessLocalPathToServerPath(strLocalPath)
    Dim strProcessedPath, strFileName, strRelPathToRoot, strFileExtension

    'Get the filename
    strFileName = right(strLocalPath,len(strLocalPath)-InStrRev(strLocalPath,"\"))
    'WScript.Echo "strFileName: """ & strFileName & """"

    'Get the relative path to the root
    strRelPathToRoot = mid(strLocalPath,len(constRootWinPath),len(strLocalPath)-(len(constRootWinPath)+len(strFileName))+1) '+1 to get the trailing slash
    'Swap back slash for forward slash
    strRelPathToRoot = replace(strRelPathToRoot,"\","/")
    'WScript.Echo "strRelPathToRoot: """ & strRelPathToRoot & """"

    'Get the file extension
    strFileExtension = right(strFileName,len(strFileName)-InStrRev(strFileName,"."))
    'WScript.Echo "strFileExtension: """ & strFileExtension & """"

    'Process the paths depending on file type
    Select Case strFileExtension
        'send swf files to our wrapper viewer on the server
        Case "swf"
            strProcessedPath = constServerDomain & "flashviewer.asp?swf=" & constRootServerPath & strRelPathToRoot & strFileName
        'Use google viewer for supported file types
        Case "docx","doc","xls","xlsx","ppt","pptx","pdf","pages","ai","psd","tiff","dxf","svg","eps","ps","ttf","xps","zip","rar"
            strProcessedPath = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" & constServerDomain & constRootServerPath & strRelPathToRoot & strFileName
        'direct file path
        Case else
            strProcessedPath = constServerDomain & constRootServerPath & strRelPathToRoot & strFileName
    End Select
    'WScript.Echo "strProcessedPath: """ & strProcessedPath & """"

    ProcessLocalPathToServerPath = strProcessedPath
End Function

' The Internet Explorer object is used, because WSH
' and VBScript don't support clipboard access by themselves.
Sub SendToClipboard(strToClipboard)
    Set objIE = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
    objIE.Navigate( "about:blank" )
    objIE.Document.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.SetData "text", strToClipboard
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub 

Sub Register
    Dim wshShell

    Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Add the required registry entries for files
    wshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\webists_serverpathtoclip\", "Copy Sever URL"
    wshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\webists_serverpathtoclip\command\", "wscript.exe """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ ""%L""", "REG_EXPAND_SZ"

    On Error Goto 0

    Set wshShell = Nothing
    WScript.Echo "Script successfully registered."
    WScript.Quit 0
End Sub


Sub UnRegister
    Dim wshShell

    Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Remove the registry entries for the files menu
    wshShell.RegDelete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\webists_serverpathtoclip\command\"
    wshShell.RegDelete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\webists_serverpathtoclip\"

    ' Remove the registry entries for the folders menu
    ' wshShell.RegDelete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\webists_serverpathtoclip\command\"
    ' wshShell.RegDelete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\webists_serverpathtoclip\"

    On Error Goto 0

    Set wshShell = Nothing
    WScript.Echo "Script successfully unregistered."
    WScript.Quit 0
End Sub


Sub Syntax
    Dim strMsg
    strMsg = "Webists_GetCorrespondingServerPath.vbs,  Version 1.00" & vbCrLf _
           & "written by Andy Brennenstuhl @ The Webists" & vbCrLf _
           & "http://www.thewebists.com" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _           
           & "Use this script to get corresponding server paths of synchronised files." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
           & "MAKE SURE TO CONFIGURE BY EDITING CONST VALUES IN THE SCRIPT." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
           & "Usage:  WSCRIPT  Webists_GetCorrespondingServerPath.vbs  ""text string"" | /Register | /Unregister" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
           & "Where:  ""text string""   is the full local path of the files you want to get the URL for" & vbCrLf _
           & "  /Register   Adds an entry ""Copy Webists Viewer Path"" to Explorers' context menu" & vbCrLf _
           & "  /UnRegister   Removes the menu entry again" _
           & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
           & "Based on 'SendClip.vbs' Written by Rob van der Woude" & vbCrLf _
           & "http://www.robvanderwoude.com"
    WScript.Echo strMsg
    WScript.Quit 1
End Sub
```

The only thing I don't like is the bit the way it uses IE to put the string in the clipboard since it asks for permission every time.

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

```
Sub SendToClipboard(strToClipboard)
    Set objIE = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
    objIE.Navigate( "about:blank" )
    objIE.Document.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.SetData "text", strToClipboard
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's in french, but I can assume the translation of some parts if you are interested. I wrote a year ago an article called [Un menu contextuel "Full PowerShell" dans l'explorer de Windows](http://www.silogix.fr/blog-silogix/Un-menu-contextuel-Full-PowerShell-dans-explorer-de-Windows) which can be translated as "a full powershell contextual menu in Windows Explorer". The concrete given sample is the MD5 hash computing of a file.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already started working on a solution using WSH.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any script at all

set the Default value of key 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Copy Server Path\Command
to:
cmd.exe /c echo "%1"|clip

Job done...
Have a nice day
PS I got this from http://www.askvg.com/registry-tweak-to-add-copy-as-path-option-in-files-and-folders-context-menu-in-windows/